# How to get page-source in utf-8 charset using java

Tags: java, android, title

I want to fetch webpage sorce in utf-8 charset format to have title,description and keywords of that page.

I got the result for (9/10) url. But, I could not get the result of some site like twitter.

I googleling many times for this I could not get perfect solution.

I use the code shown below,

```
public class TitDesKey
{
        public static void main ( String[] args ) throws IOException 
        {
            String inputLine,source= null,result_tit= null,result_des= null,result_key= null;
                try 
                {
                        URL url = new URL("http://www.twitter.com");

                        URLConnection conn =  url.openConnection();
                        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-GB; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070723 Iceweasel/2.0.0.6 (Debian-2.0.0.6-0etch1)");
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(),"utf-8"));                        


                        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
                        {
                            source=source+" "+inputLine;
                            if(inputLine.contains("</head>"))
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                }
                catch (MalformedURLException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Please Enter Write Information");
                }
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Please Enter Write Information");
                }


//              Title Data
                Pattern PATTERN_tit = Pattern.compile("<title>(.*?)</title>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE|Pattern.DOTALL);

                Matcher m_tit = PATTERN_tit.matcher(source);
                while (m_tit.find()) 
                {
                    result_tit = m_tit.group(1);
                    result_tit = result_tit.replace("/", "").trim();
                    System.out.println(result_tit);
                }       

//              Description Data
                Pattern Pattern_dis = Pattern.compile("<meta name=\"description\" content=(.*?)>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE|Pattern.DOTALL);

                Matcher m_dis = Pattern_dis.matcher(source);
                while (m_dis.find()) 
                {
                    result_des = m_dis.group(1);
                    result_des = result_des.replace("/", "").trim();
                    System.out.println(result_des);
                }   

//              Keyword Data
                Pattern Pattern_key = Pattern.compile("<meta name=\"keywords\" content=(.*?)>",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE|Pattern.DOTALL);

                Matcher m_key = Pattern_key.matcher(source);
                while (m_key.find()) 
                {
                    result_key = m_key.group(1);
                    result_key = result_key.replace("/", "").trim();
                    System.out.println(result_key);
                }   
        }
}
```

Which gives me solution in some ISO-8859 format. I also overloaded "InputStreamReader constructor" with "utf-8" charset. Which gives me result like "??????".

Please suggest me solution for this.

Thank You..:)

Comment: What happens when you execute the above code? What do you expect it to do, and what does it actually do? It seems to work fine on my laptop.

Comment: Yup, But I got response "???????????????" for twitter page source.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. This program doesn't even display the page source.

Comment: In above program String "inputline" gives me pagesource from which I got title,description and keywords.      Hope,You will understand the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your approach, and it works for me. Here is the code I used:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String inputLine;

    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.twitter.com");

        URLConnection conn =  url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty(
            "User-Agent",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-GB; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070723 Iceweasel/2.0.0.6 (Debian-2.0.0.6-0etch1)");

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(),"utf-8"));                        

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);

            // Fail if any line contains more than one sequential question mark
            assert !inputLine.contains("??");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Can you update your question with an example of the incorrectly decoded output you are getting?

Comment: Ok, I will check on my home PC. Here,in company I faced some problems in eclipse port requests. May be this was occurred due to port request. Thanks for reply....:)